# How do you verify a user based on username in firebase using custom tokens?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have followed the firebase tutorial on creating custom tokens [Create Custom Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)
 and would like to use the custom token to verify a users login as the documentation suggests is possible. Below is the code which generates a custom token but how do I use this to verify a users username at the login point. How do I incorporate the code below with `Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: customToken ?? "")`. The documentation on custom authentication [Custom Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth) seems to suggest that that the username would be hosted on a server. If firebase is functioning as a server how would that work without compromising database security through exposing user emails.

```js
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  //  databaseURL: "https://Login-Screen.firebaseio.com"
});

const uid = 'some-uid';
const displayName = "Generic Name";
// const additionalClaims = {
//   premiumAccount: true
// };

admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
.then((customToken) => {
  console.log(customToken);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("Error creating custom token: ", error)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, you will first need to authenticate user credentials on your own server endpoint first, and only when is it successful should you return a custom token to authenticate with firebase. From the docs itself:

> To achieve this, you must create a server endpoint that accepts sign-in credentials—such as a username and password—and, if the credentials are valid, returns a custom JWT. The custom JWT returned from your server can then be used by a client device to authenticate with Firebase (iOS, Android, web).

Essentially what this means is that Firebase does not care about the username or password with the `signInWithCustomToken()` function, only that the custom token is valid so you'll have to make sure the UUID you generate is unique for every user.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how could I verify the username and password using only firebase as my server would I have to make a special document in the firestore database containing usernames and passwords?

Comment: You'll have to read up on firebase authentication: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users These users are not stored in your regular firebase database, and firebase takes care of the signin/signup logic given that you are calling their APIs correctly.

Comment: You can save users on realtime database and their emails & passwords and match with the ones given by user. Then you can give the user custom token only if they matched.